What are the values of these resistors?
I have tried looking at various guides but there is nothing to indicate which way round the top resistor is. The brown bars on both ends are too similar.
How, in general, can you tell whether they are flipped left-to-right or not?
My guesses (based on this useful link https://circuitdigest.com/calculators/5-band-resistor-color-code-calculator):

Top resistor is 1k Ohms and is the correct orientation. (But it could also be a flipped 110 Ohms.)
Bottom is a 100k Ohm resistor that is flipped left-to-right (but it could also be 130 Ohms).

I do have a multimeter and when setting it to 200k Ohms, the top one measures as 0.9-1.0, and the bottom one reads as 98.1, but I don't know if these are values in Ohms or have to be scaled by some factor.
5 Band resistors and correct orientation asks similar questions but the answers there are not very conclusive. The E96 table mentioned in the answer is hard to decipher.


Does this post answer your question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117974/5-band-resistors-and-correct-orientation

It helps a little. OP has the same problem I'm having and their resistors look like the same brand. It sounds like the key is identifying the tolerance ring. The E96 table mentioned in the answer is hard to decipher but might be my best bet.

I've added some multimeter readings to the question, which I also don't know how to interpret. When setting it to 200k Ohms, the top one measures as 0.9-1.0, and the bottom one reads as 98.1, but I don't know if these are values in Ohms or have to be scaled by some factor.

Does this answer your question? 5 Band resistors and correct orientation

@JYelton that is the same link as above but thank you

Your meter is reading in kΩ on that scale, so 1k and 100k are correct.

A hint may be that they are all 1% resistors as the last ring is brown no matter how you look at it.
If you measured in 200k multimeter range, the 0.9-1.0 means 1k and the 98.1 means 100k.
You can verify by using smaller range like 10k and if the 98k goes over the current range it will show it cannot measure it. Same applies if you use 200 ohm range and try measuring the 1k.

Thank you! That really helps with interpreting the multimeter readings.
